# Swapping implications - I have no idea where to begin with this

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, natural-deduction

$(s \to p) \lor (t \to q) \vdash (s \to q) \lor (t \to p)$

This has been giving me a terrible headache. I have no idea how to go about proving this. I'm not asking for a complete solution, I just need some pointers to prove this with natural deduction...

Comment: Welcome to math SE. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Honestly I'm not even sure where to begin. I can eliminate implications to isolate $s$ and $t$, but I don't know how to establish their relations to anything else.

LEM has been no help, and neither has PBC (which is to be expected since they involve negations...)

Comment: Always remember to specify what type of proof you want and what types of rules you are allowed to use. ⊢ means that you can derivate (s → q) ∨ (t → p) from the assumption of (s → p) ∨ (t → q), which is the correct aproach to make a proof using natural deduction rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your premise is a disjunction you need to use the rule of elimination of the disjunction. First you have to assume (s → p) and then try to derivate (s → q) ∨ (t → p), and second you have to assume (t → q) and try to derivate (s → q) ∨ (t → p), wiht this tow derivations you can conlude (s → q) ∨ (t → p) by elimination of the disjunction from your premise.

I have to point out that the derivation i made is 40 steps long and it's a clasical derivation. I dont know if there's a intuitionist derivation, and my first assumption was actually ¬((s → q) ∨ (t → p)).

the proof looks like this:

1. (s → p) ∨ (t → q) - premisse
2. ¬((s → q) ∨ (t → p)) - assumption
3. s → p - assumption

4-18) derivations until you get (s → q) ∨ (t → p)

19. (s → p) → ((s → q) ∨ (t → p)) - I→
20. t → q - assumtion

21-35) derivations until you get (s → q) ∨ (t → p)

36. (t → q) → ((s → q) ∨ (t → p)) I→

After that you can eliminate the disjunction and finish the derivations with the rules you ned to aplly. I don't know if there's an easier derivation. If you want I can edit the answer and write the full derivation.

Comment: Great answer, thanks. I'm trying to work it out on my own, but I'd appreciate more detail.

Comment: Thank you. More details:  When you assume (s → p) in step 3 the idea is to derivate a contradiction (⊥) so that way you can use the EFSQ rule "ex falso sequitur quodlibet" to conclude (s → p) → ((s → q) ∨ (t → p)). You have to make more assumptions in order to accomplish this in step 4 and 5. The way you can get a contradiction is by using the assumption 2. The same apllies for step 20 (t → q). After yo colse the assuptions 3 and 20 and you eliminate the disjunction in 1 you can close assumtion 2 and use the introduction of ¬, and finaly by using the rule of E¬¬ you get the formula you want.

Answer (score 1):

We want to prove the right hand side assuming the left hand side.

Suppose $(s\to q)$ is false (with a given interpretation of the letters). 
That happens only when $s$ is true and $q$ is false.
From the conditions, if $(s\to p)$ holds, then $p$ is also true, therefore so is $(t\to p)$,
while if $(t\to q)$ holds, then $t$ must be false as $q$ is false, hence again $(t\to p)$ is true.

By the way, both sides can be written as $$(\lnot s)\lor p\lor (\lnot t)\lor q\ =\ (\lnot s)\lor q\lor (\lnot t)\lor p\,.$$