# Prove $(s \to p) \to (s \to q)$ using propositional logic

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, natural-deduction

I need to demonstrate
$(s \to p) \lor (t \to q) \vdash (s \to q) \lor (t \to p)$

I know that, if I can do something like the following, I can succesfully demonstrate the validity of this logical sentence. However, I have no idea how to get from $s \to p$ to $s \to q$.

1. $(s \to p) \lor (t \to q)$ (Promise)
2. $s \to p \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ $ (Assumption)
3. ...
4. $s \to q$
5. $(s \to q) \lor (t \to p)$

and then

1. $t \to q \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ $ (Assumption)
2. ...
3. $t \to p$
4. $(s \to q) \lor (t \to p)$

Any hint is very well appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: I gave an answer to the same formula here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3836417/swapping-implications-i-have-no-idea-where-to-begin-with-this

Comment: Indeed, @Maurocurto, I saw your answer before posting this one. However, I wanted to make sure I couldn't do it the way I'm proposing in this post. Seems like it was not the greatest idea. Anyway, thanks for it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your proof skeleton seems sensible. However, I do not think it is going to lead you to the conclusion, in this case. I think a proof by contradiction is needed.

$
\def\fitch#1#2{\quad\begin{array}{|l}#1\\\hline#2\end{array}}
\def\Ae#1{\qquad\mathbf{\forall\,Elim}\colon #1 \\}
\def\Ai#1{\qquad\mathbf{\forall\,Intro}\colon #1 \\}
\def\Ee#1{\qquad\mathbf{\exists\,E}\colon #1 \\}
\def\Ei#1{\qquad\mathbf{\exists\,Intro}\colon #1 \\}
\def\R#1{\qquad\mathbf{R}\colon #1 \\}
\def\ci#1{\qquad\mathbf{\land\,I}\colon #1 \\}
\def\ce#1{\qquad\mathbf{\land\,E}\colon #1 \\}
\def\oe#1{\qquad\mathbf{\lor\,E}\colon #1 \\}
\def\ii#1{\qquad\mathbf{\to I}\colon #1 \\}
\def\ie#1{\qquad\mathbf{\to E}\colon #1 \\}
\def\be#1{\qquad\mathbf{\leftrightarrow E}\colon #1 \\}
\def\bi#1{\qquad\mathbf{\leftrightarrow I}\colon #1 \\}
\def\qi#1{\qquad\mathbf{=I}\\}
\def\qe#1{\qquad\mathbf{=E}\colon #1 \\}
\def\ne#1{\qquad\mathbf{\neg E}\colon #1 \\}
\def\ni#1{\qquad\mathbf{\neg I}\colon #1 \\}
\def\IP#1{\qquad\mathbf{IP}\colon #1 \\}
\def\X#1{\qquad\mathbf{\bot\,Elim}\colon #1 \\}
\def\DNE#1{\qquad\mathbf{DNE}\colon #1 \\}
$

$
\fitch{(s \to p) \lor (t \to q)}{
  \fitch{\lnot((s \to q) \lor (t \to p))}{
   \fitch{s \to p}{
     \fitch{s}{
       \vdots\\
       \bot\\
       q
}\\
s \to q\\
(s \to q) \lor (t \to p)\\
}\\
\fitch{t \to q}{
 \vdots\\
 (s \to q) \lor (t \to p)
}\\
(s \to q) \lor (t \to p)\\
\bot
}\\
(s \to q) \lor (t \to p)
}
$

Comment: Could you please give me any guidance to get s -> q? I tried assuming ~s but it didn't really work.

Comment: Of course. Glad to help. What happens if you assume $t$ ? The point is deriving a statement that contradicts $\lnot((s \to q) \lor (t \to p))$.

Comment: Solid and concise answer. This was of very, very good help. Thank you :)

Comment: @henrijj - You’re very welcome :-)

Answer (score 0):

We need to prove
\begin{eqnarray}
(s \to p) \lor (t \to q) \equiv (s \to q) \lor (t \to p)
\end{eqnarray}
Note that
\begin{eqnarray}
(s \to p ) \lor (t \to q) &\equiv& (s \lor \lnot p) \lor (t \lor \lnot q)\\
&\equiv& (s\lor \lnot q) \lor (t \lor \lnot p)\\
&\equiv& (s \to q) \lor (t \to p)
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: It's derivation (natural deduction), not logical equivalence.